# Cannot change font in textGrob

Tags: fonts, r-grid

I am hoping someone can help out with custom text labels in `grid.arrange`. I have four plots that I am arranging in a column with a shared legend below. I am trying to change the font of the "left" label in `grid.arrange` but I cannot figure out how `textGrob` works for this. My current code (with `p1`-`p4` as `ggplot` objects) is:

```
windowsFonts(Georgia=windowsFont("TT Georgia"))

plots <- list(p1, p2, p3, p4)
g <- ggplotGrob(plots[[1]])
leftText <- textGrob("Percent Savings", rot=90, gp=gpar(font="Georgia"))
grid.arrange(
             do.call(arrangeGrob, c(plots, nrow=4)),
             left    = leftText,
             top     = " ",
             ncol    = 1,
             heights = c(8))
```

The font in the legend changes correctly, but the left-side font remains the default. I have tried both `font="Georgia"` and `family="Georgia"`. Any ideas how I can get this to work?

Edit: For anyone else having this problem, I finally stumbled across an answer, in textGrob the command is not `font` or `family`. It is, in fact, `fontfamily`.

Comment: Can you turn this into an [mcve](/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 12):

As the OP noted, the grid parameter is called fontfamily,

```
 grid.text("haha", gp=gpar(fontfamily = "Zapfino", cex=5))
```

[image]